# expected primary expression before int main()

Tags: c++

I know what "expected primary expression before int" means, but I've never seen the error used in this context before. It is insistently pointing toward my program header (int main()).

Could someone please enlighten me to what this means? Most of my programs start with int main() with no problem.

Thank You!

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Game.hpp"


int main(){   // <---------------- Causing error

    GameCell::Element wind("wind",10.0),
                      temp("temp",50.0),
                      precip("precip",0.0);
    std::vector<GameCell::Element> testElements;
    testElements.push_back(wind);
    testElements.push_back(temp);
    testElements.push_back(precip);

    Game * test = new Game(3,testElements);

    //GameCell GC(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, testElements, 1);
    //GC.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of `Game.hpp`?

Comment: What's in `game.hpp`?

Comment: The error has to be in the header`Game.hpp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a missing semicolon in the `"Game.hpp"` header.

Comment: Yes, the issue was in the Game.hpp error. That's the first time I've seen that error message on a completely different file. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your header file in detail. That file is basically written into
your file containing main. If there is a problem with the header file, it will cause
a problem in your file containing main.